# How to avoid thumbs.db files in compression

Tags: compression, 7zip, winzip

Is there a 7zip or winzip command to use so that the compression avoids thumbs.db files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 7zip,**-x** is the file exclusion option switch.

```
7z.exe a test.7z C:test* -r -x!thumbs.db
```

See **Excluding Files** at the following [link](http://www.codejacked.com/zip-up-files-from-the-command-line/).

Comment: I needed this for .DS_Store on MacOS X, but what I didn't realize I needed every time was `-r`, which is the secret sauce here. Thanks!